# When does $\int \frac{dx}{x} = \ln|x|$ and when $\int \frac{dx}{x} = \ln(x)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Sorry for the provocative question but I am often see a solution where the absolute value is neglect for example:

$$
\begin{cases}
xuu_x+yuu_y=u^2-1,  x>0\\
u(x,x^2)=x^3\\
\end{cases}
$$

We look at:

$$\frac{dx}{xu}=\frac{dy}{yu}=\frac{du}{u^2-1}$$

We solve:
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{xu}=\frac{dy}{yu}\\
\frac{dx}{xu}=\frac{du}{u^2-1}\\
\end{cases}$$

for $$\frac{dx}{xu}=\frac{dy}{yu}$$ we can multiple by $u\neq 0$:

$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}$$

which is:

$$\ln(x)=\ln|y|+c^*_1\rightarrow \ln|y|-\ln(x)=c^*_1\rightarrow \ln(\frac{|y|}{x})=c^*_1\rightarrow \frac{|y|}{x}=c_1$$

but on the recitation answer the solved:

$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}\rightarrow \ln(x)=\ln(y)+c^*_1$$

Why can this be done? What am I missing?

Comment: Lots of people, including ODE textbook authors, are unfortunately sloppy with these things. You're right that the absolute value should be taken into account.

Comment: The problem you have stated appears to have the explicit restriction $x > 0$. In this case $|x|=x$ and so the absolute value can be neglected.

Comment: @LeeMosher: The question concerns $|y|$, I think.

Comment: @HansLundmark yes, I do not understand why it is $ln(y)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically speaking, although the expression $\displaystyle\int\frac1x\,dx=\ln|x|+C$ is correct as far as it goes, there is a discontinuity at $x=0,$ requiring the flexibility of different constants of integration. This integral is really only defined on an interval not containing zero. So what you should really write is this:
$$\int\frac1x\,dx=\begin{cases}\ln(x)+C_1, & x>0\\ \ln(-x)+C_2,\quad & x<0 \end{cases}. $$
We can check that this is correct by differentiating each piece. For $x>0,$ we have
$$\frac{d}{dx}[\ln(x)+C_1]=\frac1x. $$
For $x<0,$ we have
$$\frac{d}{dx}[\ln(-x)+C_2]=\frac{1}{-x}\,(-1)=\frac1x, $$
as required.

Comment: so we assume that $y>0$?

Comment: Not necessarily. All you really have to assume is that $y\not=0.$ Then, depending on whether $y>0$ or $y<0,$ you take the appropriate expression.